# Can't click any buttons inside Chrome history with Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: c#, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to delete all of my history, cookies, cache, everything, after the end of all my tests that run. I can get into Chrome's history just fine, but for some reason selenium can't find the element by the ID. I even tried using `SendKeys` to tab through a few times and press enter but that doesn't work either.

```
Driver.Keyboard.SendKeys($"{Keys.Control + "h"}");
Thread.Sleep(5000);
Driver.FindElementById("clear-browsing-data").Click();
var checkboxDiv = Driver.FindElementById("clear-data-checkboxes");
List<IWebElement> checkboxes = checkboxDiv.FindElements(By.TagName("input")).ToList();
foreach (IWebElement checkbox in checkboxes)
{
    if (!checkbox.Selected)
    {
        checkbox.Click();
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

(Yes, some of the checking of checking to see if the checkboxes are checked(wow a lot of checks) probably needs some refining, but will address that later)
I can't even simply click on `clear-browsing-data`. Any ideas why? Or any alternatives to what I am trying to accomplish? Thanks in advance.

Comment: is your url `chrome://history-frame` ?   there is no iframe if you use that url.

Answer (score 1):

The checkboxes and `clear-browsing-data` button are inside `iframe`. You need to switch to it first.

In addition, `Driver.Keyboard.SendKeys($"{Keys.Control + "h"}");` opens new tab, you need to switch to it to locate the frame.

```
// switch to the new tab
Driver.SwitchTo().Window(Driver.WindowHandles[1]);

// switch to the frame
Driver.SwitchTo().Frame("history"); // history is the frame name attribute, you can also use id attribute, WebElement or index
```

And to switch back

```
// get out of the frame
Driver.SwitchTo().DefaultContent();

// switch back to the website tab
Driver.SwitchTo().Window(Driver.WindowHandles[0]);
```

Comment: I get NoSuchFrameException. "No frame element found with name or id history". Tried it using indexes too, still no luck.

Comment: @DannyGoodall You tried it after the history page was opened?

Comment: @DannyGoodall You can also try Driver.SwitchTo().Frame(Driver.FindElementByTagName("iframe"));

Comment: Yup, still getting the same error even with your latest suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

```
[Test]
    public void ClearChromeHistory()
    {
        //Navigate to History
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("chrome://history/");

        //Switch to IFrame
        driver.SwitchTo().Frame("history");

        Thread.Sleep(5000); //Static wait is not recommended

        //Click on 'Clear Browsing Data' Button
        IWebElement clearBrowsingDataButton =  driver.FindElement(By.Id("clear-browsing-data"));
        clearBrowsingDataButton.Click();

        Thread.Sleep(2000); //Static wait is not recommended

        //Swich to Settings IFrame on 'chrome://settings/clearBrowserData' URL
        driver.SwitchTo().Frame("settings");

        Thread.Sleep(5000); //Static wait is not recommended

        //Click on 'Browsing History' checkbox
        IWebElement ClearHistoryCheckbox = driver.FindElement(By.Id("delete-browsing-history-checkbox"));
        ClearHistoryCheckbox.Click();
    }
```

**This is working perfectly for me.**

You can skip clicking on 'Clear Browsing Data' button, you can directly navigate to `chrome://settings/clearBrowserData` and then switch to settings frame and tick/untick checkboxes.

I hope this helps!